# Any way to use an object's function as the value for jqGrid data array?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid to display an array of JavaScript objects. One of the values I want to display is a function, not a property, of the object. In the example below, all the values are properties except 'timeliness()' which is a function which calculates the difference between delivery and due dates and returns a timeliness value.

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
  datatype: 'local',
  data: assignments,
  colNames: ['Project', 'Date Due', 'Date Delivered', "Timeliness"],
  colModel: [
    {name: 'project.title', index: 'project.title', width: 100}, 
    {name: 'title', index: 'title', width: 250}, 
    {name: 'dueDate',index: 'dueDate', width: 100},
    {name: 'deliveryDate', index: 'deliveryDate', width: 100},
    {name: 'timeliness()', index: 'timeliness()', width: 100}
  ],
  sortname: 'Project',
  rowNum: 10000,
  sortorder: 'asc',
  viewrecords: true,
  loadonce: true,
  gridview: true,
  height: 'auto',
  caption: 'Projects'
});
```

I've tried it as shown and the function isn't called and no value is returned. I've tried without the parenthesis (e.g. name: timeliness) and as expected it returns the function definition.

Using a formatter works, but it leaves me unable to sort on the column (and this is a column the user would like to sort on). Another way I've thought to work around the problem is simply creating a new property for this object and setting it on all the objects just before I deliver it to the grid to be displayed (once in the grid I don't expect the values to change). Just interested in learning if this is possible in jqGrid and maybe I'm just not handling this field correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Another way I've thought to work around the problem is simply creating a new property for this object and setting it on all the objects just before I deliver it to the grid to be displayed (once in the grid I don't expect the values to change)

This is the easiest solution. Keep in mind that jqGrid is designed to handle many different types of data sources, and most of them involve data from an external source (such as XML or JSON) where a function would not be applicable.